# App Engine dispatch.yaml doesn't affect service versions without traffic

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

Hi we are using App engine with many new and legacy java services.

- we have 1 new frontend angular app and multiple services in java8

we access the application directly using without custom domains

- frontend-dot-project-id.appspot.com
- legacyapp-dot-project-id.appspot.com

My issue is the dispatch file doesn't affect app URLs with version specified
which broke the apis in the applications if opened in version url

for example :

- **frontend-dot-project-id.appspot.com/api/v2** => works
- **ver-dot-frontend-dot-project-id.appspot.com/api/v2** => doesn't work and will take me to frontend application as if there is no dispatch routes deployed

my dispatch.yaml looks something like this:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/api/v2/*"
    service: api-back
  - url: "*/api/v1/*"
    service: legacy-back
```

my app.yaml for the angular app

```
service: frontend
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
  - url: /(.*\.(css|eot|gz|html|ico|js|map|png|jpg|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|json)(|\.map))$
    static_files: dist/app/\1
    upload: dist/app/(.*)(|\.map)
  - url: /.*
    static_files: dist/app/index.html
    upload: dist/app/.*
    login: required

skip_files:
  - e2e/
  - node_modules/
  - src/
  - coverage
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.md$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
  - ^LICENSE
```

thanks in advance